# How can I know what version of wif is installed on my server

Tags: windows, asp.net-mvc-4, authentication, wif

I have a windows 2008 R2 Server, my apps use framework 4.5
`<compilation targetFramework="4.5.1">`
but suddenly one of my apps stopped authenticating against my authentication app in the same server. others do, others just dont the page the page redirect well to the auth site and auth ok, but on the way back to my app the page show the error"connection reset" each time I Try, I see a warning in the event viewer

```
Exception type: HttpException 
    Exception message: Cannot redirect after HTTP headers have been sent.
```

If I try this app in another server or local in my computer it authenticates just fine.

So I think is a matter of WIF versions installed on the server, but I'm Not sure.
Exist any way to know What Wif Versions are installed?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved,
It was due to miss information on the third app webconfig, was the certificate information was invalid, so it tried to find a certificate that didnt exist on the server.